# How to use Multiplication with numbers and variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
"use strict";
var red_id = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block betButton")[0];
var green_id = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block betButton")[0];
var black_id = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-inverse btn-lg btn-block betButton")[0];

document.getElementById('betAmount').value = 'NaN';
red_id.id = 'red';
green_id.id = 'green';
black_id.id = 'black';

setInterval(automated, 40000);

function automated() {

var roll_history = $('#past')[0].childNodes[9].textContent;
var roll_hisLast = $('#past')[0].childNodes[8].textContent;
var red_button = document.getElementById('red');
var black_button = document.getElementById('black');
var base_bet = 1;

function thisRoll(roll_history) {
 var this_roll;
 if (roll_history === 0) {
  this_roll = 'green';
 } else if ((roll_history >= 1) && (roll_history <= 7)) {
  this_roll = 'red';
 } else if ((roll_history >= 8) && (roll_history <= 14)) {
  this_roll = 'black';
 }
 return this_roll;
}
var thisRoll = thisRoll(roll_history);
console.log(thisRoll);

function LastRoll(roll_hisLast) {

 var last_roll;
 if (roll_hisLast === 0) {
  last_roll = 'green';
 } else if ((roll_hisLast >= 1) && (roll_hisLast <= 7)) {
  last_roll = 'red';
 } else if ((roll_hisLast >= 8) && (roll_hisLast <= 14)) {
  last_roll = 'black';
 }
 return last_roll;
}
var lastRoll = LastRoll(roll_hisLast);
console.log(LastRoll);

function compare(thisRoll, lastRoll) {
 var win_lose;
 if (thisRoll !== lastRoll) {
  win_lose = 'lose';
 } else {
  win_lose = 'win';
 }
 return win_lose;
}
var winLose = compare(thisRoll, lastRoll);
console.log(winLose);

var input_last = document.getElementById('betAmount').value;

function betInputLast(input_last) {

 var last;
 last = input_last;
 return last;
}
var lastXX = betInputLast(input_last);
console.log(lastXX);

function betInputLastX(lastXX) {

 var fix_X;
 if (isNaN(lastXX)) {
  fix_X = base_bet;
 }
 return fix_X;
}
var lastX = betInputLastX(X);
console.log(lastX);

function betInput(winLose) {

 var x;
 if (winLose === 'win') {
  x = base_bet;
 } else if (winLose === 'lose') {
  x = lastX * 2;
 }
 return x;
}
var X = betInput(winLose);
console.log(X);

var bet_input = document.getElementById('betAmount').value = X;

function bet(thisRoll, X) {

 var log;
 if (thisRoll === 'red') {
  red_button.click();
  log = 'Betting ' + X + ' on red';
 } else if (thisRoll === 'black') {
  black_button.click();
  log = 'Betiing ' + X + ' on black';
 }
 return log;
}
var Log = bet(thisRoll, X);
console.log(Log);
}
```

```html
<div class="roulette"><div class="well text-center" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:25px; padding: 20px;">
   <div class="progress text-center" style="height:50px;margin-bottom:10px;">
    <span id="banner">Rolling in 24.93...</span>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" id="counter" style="width: 83.1432%; overflow: hidden;"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="case" style="margin-bottom: 15px; background-position: -208px 0px;">
    <div id="pointer"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="past">
              <div data-rollid="696912" class="ball ball-0">0</div>
              <div data-rollid="696913" class="ball ball-8">9</div>
              <div data-rollid="696914" class="ball ball-1">5</div>
              <div data-rollid="696915" class="ball ball-1">3</div>
              <div data-rollid="696916" class="ball ball-1">6</div>
              <div data-rollid="696917" class="ball ball-8">14</div>
              <div data-rollid="696918" class="ball ball-1">3</div>
              <div data-rollid="696919" class="ball ball-8">11</div>
              <div data-rollid="696920" class="ball ball-8">10</div>
              <div data-rollid="696921" class="ball ball-0">0</div>
            </div>
   <div style="margin: 20px 0px;">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-btn bet-buttons">
     <span class="balance"> 
      <span>Balance: </span>
      <span id="dongers_r"></span>
      <span id="balance_r" class="">15020</span> <i style="cursor:pointer; margin-left: 5px;" class="fa fa-refresh noselect" id="getbal_r"></i>
     </span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Bet amount..." id="betAmount">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger betshort" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default betshort" data-action="10">+10</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default betshort" data-action="100">+100</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default betshort" data-action="1000">+1000</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default betshort" data-action="half">1/2</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default betshort" data-action="double">x2</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary betshort" data-action="max">Max</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-xs-4 betBlock" style="padding-right:0px">
    <div class="panel panel-default bet-panel" id="panel11-7-b">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="1" data-upper="7"><span> 1 to 7</span><span></span></button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default bet-panel" id="panel1-7-m">
     <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
      <div class="my-row">
       <div class="text-center"><span class="mytotal">0</span></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default bet-panel" id="panel1-7-t">
     <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
      <div class="total-row">
       <div class="text-center">Total bet: <span class="total">24485</span></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 betBlock">
    <div class="panel panel-default bet-panel" id="panel0-0-b">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="0" data-upper="0">0</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default bet-panel" id="panel0-0-m">
     <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
      <div class="my-row">
       <div class="text-center"><span class="mytotal">0</span></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default bet-panel" id="panel0-0-t">
     <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
      <div class="total-row">
       <div class="text-center">Total bet: <span class="total">13780</span></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 betBlock" style="padding-left:0px">
    <div class="panel panel-default bet-panel" id="panel8-14-b">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="8" data-upper="14"><span> 8 to 14</span><span></span></button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default bet-panel" id="panel8-14-m">
     <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
      <div class="my-row">
       <div class="text-center"><span class="mytotal">0</span></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default bet-panel" id="panel8-14-t">
     <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
      <div class="total-row">
       <div class="text-center">Total bet: <span class="total">6572</span></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div></div>
```

The function that dosen't work is `function betInput(winLose)` that have to multiply with `2` if `winLose = 'lose'` it happens first time but after that the output is only 2, were it should be multiplyed with `2`.

I know this is peace of cake but i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Did you check your console? It gives an `Uncaught TypeError`.

Comment: Well you never update lastX....

Comment: @crowes yeah i checked, and that is what confused me. There was no error

Comment: @Crowes @McMuffin  I think the error is coming because you've haven't added any HTML in the snippet & the js code is trying to perform DOM operation on `betAmount`

Comment: @epascarello so what you are saying is, that if i change the function `betInputLastX` to `function betInputLastX(lastXX) {

 var fix_X;
 if (isNaN(lastXX)) {
  fix_X = base_bet;
 } else {
  fix_X = lastXX;
 }
 return fix_X;
}
var lastX = betInputLastX(X);
console.log(lastX);` it will work?

Comment: add the HTML also.

Comment: @aManHasNoName it is when i am running it in the browser console

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few problems here. I'm not totally sure what you are shooting for but these things might help.

I think you my have some scope issues here. The function `automated` gets called every so often on a timer. Each time that function is called all of the variables that are defined within `automated` using `var` statements are fresh, new variables. Consider defining `lastX` and `X` before the definition of `automated`. This way those values will be remembered for each successive call to `automated`.

Next consider the function `betInputLastX`. The only case that is covered is the initial case where the parameter value is `NaN`. I think that there should be an `else` branch that would assign `X` to `fix_X`. If this is not done the `fix_X` value is returned as undefined, and not useful in successive functions.

With these changes the output will give a sequence that looks some thing like `NaN, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ....` I'm not sure that all your problems are solved at this point but I hope these suggestions can get back on track to continue developing.

Comment: I have tried change it to `function betInputLastX(lastXX) { var fix_X; if (isNaN(lastXX)) { fix_X = base_bet; } else { fix_X = lastXX; } return fix_X; } var lastX = betInputLastX(X); console.log(lastX);` but that didn't work. I don't think i can define `lastX` and `X` before `automated` because i need `lastX` to be the value of `X` from the previous time the function was executed, and i need `X` to be updated by `betInput` every time `automated` is executed to fill in `var bet_input = document.getElementById('betAmount').value = X;`